# Matlab handle class handle size

Tags: matlab, memory-management, handle

I have a handle class and an array in which I store multiple copies of handles of the class objects I produced (sometimes up to 1000 copies of a single handle). I assumed the handles to the objects themselves would use little memory.

In a post http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255117 someone mentioned the handles would be 4 bytes. However if I do a `whos` on a object handle I get 112 bytes. Which is too much for my current application. Is this normal?

So how do I keep the memory usage down? I can imagine a solution in which I can map the handles (with a `container.map`) to a uint32 number (4 bytes) and then using that number to represent them in my array of handle copies. It's a bit dirty though because each time I want to get the data from my object I need to go through the mapping.

Any better ideas?
Thanks!

As per request an example:

```
classdef Test < handle
end

>> z = Test();
>> whos z
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
  z         1x1               112  Test  
>> y = [z z z z z z z z z]; %an array of copies of the handle
```

However this is confusing me:

```
>> y = [z z z];
>> whos y
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
  y         1x3               128  Test               

>> y = [z z z z];
>> whos y
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
  y         1x4               136  Test
```

Comment: Good question. Might we have some small self-contained example to help us answer your question?

Comment: Which matlab version are you using? With ML2013a 32bit it's 56 bytes for the base class and 4 bytes for the handle. In your case it seems to be 8 bytes for the handle and 108 bytes for the base class.

Comment: * 104 bytes for the base class, not 108

Comment: I have Matlab R2013a. Weird... Maybe the Linux version (which I run) is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whos displays the size of the object including the 4 bytes reference. Your object itself would be 108 bytes and the handle adds another 4 bytes, but the 108 bytes are shared. You can not sum up the memory in whos to get the total allocated memory.

Take a look at the size of y, it should be numel(y)*4+108

Comment: Ah yes it seems you are right except that the handles seem to be 8 bytes. So 112 - 8 = 104.
4*8+104 = 136 like in my last example.

So you are saying that the handles themselves are 8 bytes then. Weird that the whos of the array contains the 104 bytes. What if I make a second object called v and add it to the array? Will I have 104+104+ numel(y) * 8?